# Try/Except - If Exception occurs, execution stops. while True creates endless loop

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I'm brand new to Python, my apologies if this is a trivial question. Have been googling for hours unsuccessfully.

I have a code that takes latitudes/longitudes from an Excel file and returns addresses using an API.

If Excel cells contain wrong Lat/Longs, it returns IndexError. In that case it just stops execution even if the next row contains correct (geocodable) Lat/Longs. I tried using while True, but it just keeps writing the results excluding the part after Except.

E.g. Excel has the following columns/values:

```
Lat        Long
38.872476 -77.062334
1          23.456789
38.873411 -77.060907
```

The 1st line has correct Lat/Long, the 2nd incorrect, the 3rd correct. In the output file it shows the address of the 1st row and says "N/A" for the 2nd row, but ignores the 3rd row and stops execution.

```
try:
    for row in range(rows):
        row+=1
        latitude = float(sheet.row_values(row)[0])
        longitude = float(sheet.row_values(row)[1])
        reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((latitude, longitude))
        out_file.write("(" + str(latitude) + ", " + str(longitude) + ") location: " + str(reverse_geocode_result[1]['formatted_address']) + "\n")

except IndexError:
    out_file.write("N/A")
else:
    out_file.write("(" + str(latitude) + ", " + str(longitude) + ") location: " + str(reverse_geocode_result[1]['formatted_address']) + "\n")

print "Done."
```

Comment: You probably want to put the `try`, `except` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to stick your `try` inside your `for` loop.

```
for row in range(rows):
    try:
        # Get the values
    except IndexError:
        out_file.write("N/A")
    else:
        out_file.write(...)

print "Done."
```

That way if there is an error, you'll write `"N/A"`, but then be able to continue to the next element in the `range`.

Comment: Oh, it was that simple! Thanks so much, will accept your answer in a few mins :)